# Fastest way to manipulate bigdata in R

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata, rsqlite

I have 40+ CSV files with each being around 400MB. What I need to do is to read these 40+ big csv files, do some manipulation and formatting on them (such as commonize date formats, separating dates to months,day,etc..), and combine them in a single data frame. I have searched in the previous post about the quickest way to read these CSV files to be "fread" but even when I used fread, it took approx. 14 seconds for reading each file, and leaves me with a pretty significant runtime. I tried using SQLite through RSQLite for a single csv files:

```
setwd("raw_data/sqldatabase")
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="test_db.sqlite") ## will make, if not present
dbWriteTable(conn=db, name="your_table", value="testdata.csv", row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

However, even using SQLite it took a considerable amount of time. What can be used to quickly read 40+ big csv folders into a "space" that makes manipulation on is very fast?

If I were to upload the data to a database once, and if it were to make the manipulation very fast from than on, I would be still fine, but the final folder (once merge is complete) expected to be 25+GB. So I am trying to find the most efficient way to manipulate the data

Comment: Assuming you don't have a system with 64+ gb of ram, you may want to consider looking into Arrow datasets. Another consideration would be to use the map/reduce framework to chunk the csvs into groups of ~10 and complete the operations on each chunk before reducing everything to one data frame right at the end. Is every column in each .csv strictly necessary? It's often possible to severely reduce the size of each .csv by dropping unnecessary columns.

Comment: You may not need such a big machine. Csv size is bigger than R's in-memory data.frame/data.table. fread takes 14s to read 400mb file? I wouldn't expect. Check how many threads you are using, and verbose=T. You can post it to GH issue tracker. I doubt you will find anything faster than DT. What could eventually speed up reading many files is to setDTthreads(1) and read them using parallel pkg simultaneously.

Comment: If you are not planning on shifting your data management (in the long term) to a DBMS that handles that volume well, then one technique could include a "parquet datamart", where for each individual file (only one at a time), you read the CSV file, format/augment as desired, save as a parquet, then move on (not attempting to save it in memory, perhaps explicitly `rm(x)` then `gc()` to reclaim memory). Then use [`arrow::open-data`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html) on the *directory*, allowing lazy evaluation of your data (but this does not enable loading all data into ram).

Comment: You can also do parallel calculations with the R package doParallel. With the R package doParallel, you could read multiple CSV files at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative might be a "parquet datamart". The premise here:

1. For each file, read in the CSV, format/augment/filter/select as desired, then save as a `.parquet` file.

   - Optional: write into multiple `.parquet` files after splitting on one or more indexable (categorical/ordinal) columns.
2. Read the data using [`arrow::open_dataset`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/dataset.html), `dplyr`, and their lazy-evaluation. While this does not allow you to read the entire dataset into memory at one time, it does give you access to all of the data in smaller chunks, as if it were one big dataset.

This is still compatible with `data.table` for the in-memory work, using `arrow` to access the data lazily. While my example below uses `data.table`, it is not required, and in fact introduces an extra step or two in order to convert the sample data from `tibble` to `data.table`. I suggest this due to the large nature of the data and because you tagged it, not because it is required.

Some things to note for both examples:

1. The dataset object `ds` reflects all 336,776 rows of data, though the object is rather small (just an environment with references to files and metadata in them).
2. The initial filtering above returns a lazy reference, not the data itself. To get the actual data, one needs to add `collect()`. Don't try to do this on the whole data unless you know that it can fit into memory.
3. Recall that the original object was a `data.table` (from `fread`), and `write_parquet` keeps several of the frame's attributes (including that), so when we realize the data below, it will be a `data.table`.
4. ***However***, while the `collect`ed data is `data.table`, changes to that collected data will not migrate back to the parquet file itself. This means if you do something like `collect(ds)[, newcol := 1]`, doing another `collect(ds)` will not have the `newcol` in it. It's worth noting that `parquet` files are immutable once written: they cannot be updated or appended-to.

---

Practical example: `nycflights13::flights`. The data contains 336,776 rows of *"Airline on-time data for all flights departing NYC in 2013"*. For the sake of this example, I'll split the data randomly into 5 frames and save into CSV files.

```r
set.seed(42)
ind <- sample(1:5, size = nrow(nycflights13::flights), replace = TRUE)
head(ind)

dir.create("csv")
i <- 1L
for (dat in split(nycflights13::flights, ind)) {
  fwrite(dat, sprintf("csv/%s.csv", i))
  i <- i + 1L
}
file.info(Sys.glob("csv/*"))
#              size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
# csv/1.csv 6274623 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:54  no
# csv/2.csv 6265804 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:52  no
# csv/3.csv 6261533 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:43  no
# csv/4.csv 6260298 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:49  no
# csv/5.csv 6235815 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:40 2022-09-19 05:21:46  no
```

For the two examples below, I'm not going to do any data filtering/formatting/augmentation; other than highlight where one would do this, I'll assume you know what you need to do to each individual CSV file before saving.

### Plan 1: no indexes

```r
dir.create("datamart")
for (fn in Sys.glob("csv/*.csv")) {
  X <- fread(fn)
  arrow::write_parquet(X, file.path("datamart", paste0(basename(fn), ".parquet")))
  rm(X)
  gc() # optional, might help
}
file.info(Sys.glob("datamart/*"))
#                           size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
# datamart/1.csv.parquet 1251629 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:26:28 2022-09-19 05:26:28 2022-09-19 05:35:59  no
# datamart/2.csv.parquet 1249485 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:26:45 2022-09-19 05:26:45 2022-09-19 05:35:59  no
# datamart/3.csv.parquet 1249652 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:26:47 2022-09-19 05:26:47 2022-09-19 05:35:59  no
# datamart/4.csv.parquet 1249772 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:26:48 2022-09-19 05:26:48 2022-09-19 05:35:59  no
# datamart/5.csv.parquet 1245022 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:26:49 2022-09-19 05:26:49 2022-09-19 05:35:59  no
```

Reading in the data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)
ds <- open_dataset("datamart")

nrow(ds)
# [1] 336776
object.size(ds) # environment
# 504 bytes
with(ls.objects(envir = ds), sum(Size))
# [1] 145888

ds %>%
  filter(month == 1, between(day, 1, 10))
# FileSystemDataset (query)
# year: int32
# month: int32
# day: int32
# dep_time: int32
# sched_dep_time: int32
# dep_delay: int32
# arr_time: int32
# sched_arr_time: int32
# arr_delay: int32
# carrier: string
# flight: int32
# tailnum: string
# origin: string
# dest: string
# air_time: int32
# distance: int32
# hour: int32
# minute: int32
# time_hour: timestamp[us, tz=UTC]
# * Filter: ((month == 1) and ((day >= 1) and (day <= 10)))
# See $.data for the source Arrow object
```

```r
ds %>%
  filter(month == 1, between(day, 1, 10)) %>%
  collect()
#        year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay carrier flight tailnum origin   dest
#       <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <int>    <int>          <int>     <int>  <char>  <int>  <char> <char> <char>
#    1:  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25      DL    461  N668DN    LGA    ATL
#    2:  2013     1     1      555            600        -5      913            854        19      B6    507  N516JB    EWR    FLL
#    3:  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      709            723       -14      EV   5708  N829AS    LGA    IAD
#    4:  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      923            937       -14      UA   1124  N53441    EWR    SFO
#    5:  2013     1     1      559            600        -1      941            910        31      AA    707  N3DUAA    LGA    DFW
#    6:  2013     1     1      607            607         0      858            915       -17      UA   1077  N53442    EWR    MIA
#    7:  2013     1     1      613            610         3      925            921         4      B6    135  N635JB    JFK    RSW
#    8:  2013     1     1      615            615         0      833            842        -9      DL    575  N326NB    EWR    ATL
#    9:  2013     1     1      623            610        13      920            915         5      AA   1837  N3EMAA    LGA    MIA
#   10:  2013     1     1      624            630        -6      840            830        10      MQ   4599  N518MQ    LGA    MSP
#   ---                                                                                                                           
# 8823:  2013     1    10     2038           2045        -7     2140           2154       -14      B6   1178  N640JB    EWR    BOS
# 8824:  2013     1    10     2040           2040         0     2351           2357        -6      B6    677  N809JB    JFK    LAX
# 8825:  2013     1    10     2054           2100        -6     2202           2207        -5      US   2144  N952UW    LGA    BOS
# 8826:  2013     1    10     2058           2100        -2     2229           2225         4      WN    530  N443WN    LGA    MDW
# 8827:  2013     1    10     2104           2110        -6     2337           2355       -18      B6    529  N507JB    EWR    MCO
# 8828:  2013     1    10     2129           2130        -1      148            218       -30      B6    701  N193JB    JFK    SJU
# 8829:  2013     1    10     2159           2159         0     2247           2300       -13      EV   4519  N13124    EWR    BWI
# 8830:  2013     1    10     2320           2250        30       16           2354        22      B6   1018  N612JB    JFK    BOS
# 8831:  2013     1    10       NA            635        NA       NA            940        NA      AA    711  N3CDAA    LGA    DFW
# 8832:  2013     1    10       NA            700        NA       NA           1007        NA      UA    719            EWR    DFW
# 5 variables not shown: [air_time <int>, distance <int>, hour <int>, minute <int>, time_hour <POSc>]
```

### Plan B: using `year` and `month` as nested subdirectories

In your data, an indexable field might be:

- the original CSV filename, if you want to be able to filter on that
- one or more innate categorical/ordinal fields (not continuous)

There is a balance between convenience and usability: if a categorical variable has 20,000 possible values, then it might be too many and one will lose much efficiency. The more directories/files found within the subdirectories, the longer it will take to call `open_dataset` before you can do something with it. I don't have easy metrics for this.

Note: one might be able to use `write_dataset`, the counterpart to our `open_dataset` above. It handles `partitions=` in the same fashion. However, if you are not certain that each level within the partition fields are unique to a file (for instance, in my sample data I have `month == 1` in all CSV files), then each CSV file read would overwrite some data from the previous write. In this case, as I'll demonstrate here, I'll write to subdirectories manually.

```r
# ensures .parquet files are additive
addfile <- function(dat, base, by) {
  thisdir <- do.call(file.path, as.list(c(base, paste(names(by), unname(by), sep = "="))))
  dir.create(thisdir, recursive = TRUE, showWarnings = FALSE)
  existing <- list.files(thisdir)
  thisfile <- sprintf("%i.parquet", length(existing) + 1)
  arrow::write_parquet(dat, file.path(thisdir, thisfile))
}
dir.create("datamart2")
for (fn in Sys.glob("csv/*.csv")) {
  X <- fread(fn)
  X[, addfile(.SD, "datamart2", by = .BY), by = .(year, month)]
  rm(X)
  gc() # optional
}
file.info(Sys.glob("datamart2/*/*/*"))
#                                          size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
# datamart2/year=2013/month=1/1.parquet  133469 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=1/2.parquet  132760 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=1/3.parquet  134069 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=1/4.parquet  132404 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=1/5.parquet  136424 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=10/1.parquet 140490 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=10/2.parquet 139362 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=10/3.parquet 138570 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=10/4.parquet 137501 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=10/5.parquet 137426 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=11/1.parquet 133714 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=11/2.parquet 134291 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=11/3.parquet 133199 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=11/4.parquet 136152 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=11/5.parquet 133310 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=12/1.parquet 141743 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=12/2.parquet 142030 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=12/3.parquet 139573 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=12/4.parquet 140515 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=12/5.parquet 140059 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=2/1.parquet  126203 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=2/2.parquet  126481 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=2/3.parquet  126348 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=2/4.parquet  126618 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=2/5.parquet  123947 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=3/1.parquet  140691 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=3/2.parquet  142811 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=3/3.parquet  142415 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=3/4.parquet  140573 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=3/5.parquet  138510 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=4/1.parquet  140734 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=4/2.parquet  140707 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=4/3.parquet  140507 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=4/4.parquet  141896 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=4/5.parquet  141182 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=5/1.parquet  139517 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=5/2.parquet  140546 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=5/3.parquet  143193 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=5/4.parquet  139979 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=5/5.parquet  141259 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=6/1.parquet  143405 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=6/2.parquet  142591 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=6/3.parquet  142106 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=6/4.parquet  143012 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=6/5.parquet  141489 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=7/1.parquet  145064 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=7/2.parquet  143898 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=7/3.parquet  144104 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=7/4.parquet  146099 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=7/5.parquet  146616 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=8/1.parquet  145155 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=8/2.parquet  143314 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=8/3.parquet  145334 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=8/4.parquet  144581 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=8/5.parquet  145998 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=9/1.parquet  135902 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25 2022-09-19 05:53:25  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=9/2.parquet  135525 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26 2022-09-19 05:53:26  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=9/3.parquet  136012 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28 2022-09-19 05:53:28  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=9/4.parquet  137506 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29 2022-09-19 05:53:29  no
# datamart2/year=2013/month=9/5.parquet  133894 FALSE  666 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30 2022-09-19 05:53:30  no
```

Reading data is the same as in part 1, though note that the indexes `year` and `month` are the last two columns instead of the first two:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)
ds <- open_dataset("datamart2")
nrow(ds)
# [1] 336776
object.size(ds) # environment
# 504 bytes
with(ls.objects(envir = ds), sum(Size))
# [1] 155896

ds %>%
  filter(month == 1, between(day, 1, 10))
# FileSystemDataset (query)
# day: int32
# dep_time: int32
# sched_dep_time: int32
# dep_delay: int32
# arr_time: int32
# sched_arr_time: int32
# arr_delay: int32
# carrier: string
# flight: int32
# tailnum: string
# origin: string
# dest: string
# air_time: int32
# distance: int32
# hour: int32
# minute: int32
# time_hour: timestamp[us, tz=UTC]
# year: int32
# month: int32
# * Filter: ((month == 1) and ((day >= 1) and (day <= 10)))
# See $.data for the source Arrow object

ds %>%
  filter(month == 1, between(day, 1, 10)) %>%
  collect()
#         day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay carrier flight tailnum origin   dest air_time
#       <int>    <int>          <int>     <int>    <int>          <int>     <int>  <char>  <int>  <char> <char> <char>    <int>
#    1:     1      517            515         2      830            819        11      UA   1545  N14228    EWR    IAH      227
#    2:     1      542            540         2      923            850        33      AA   1141  N619AA    JFK    MIA      160
#    3:     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18      B6    725  N804JB    JFK    BQN      183
#    4:     1      557            600        -3      838            846        -8      B6     79  N593JB    JFK    MCO      140
#    5:     1      558            600        -2      849            851        -2      B6     49  N793JB    JFK    PBI      149
#    6:     1      559            600        -1      854            902        -8      UA   1187  N76515    EWR    LAS      337
#    7:     1      600            600         0      851            858        -7      B6    371  N595JB    LGA    FLL      152
#    8:     1      615            615         0     1039           1100       -21      B6    709  N794JB    JFK    SJU      182
#    9:     1      635            635         0     1028            940        48      AA    711  N3GKAA    LGA    DFW      248
#   10:     1      655            655         0     1021           1030        -9      DL   1415  N3763D    JFK    SLC      294
#   ---                                                                                                                        
# 8823:    10     2038           2045        -7     2140           2154       -14      B6   1178  N640JB    EWR    BOS       40
# 8824:    10     2040           2040         0     2351           2357        -6      B6    677  N809JB    JFK    LAX      343
# 8825:    10     2054           2100        -6     2202           2207        -5      US   2144  N952UW    LGA    BOS       34
# 8826:    10     2058           2100        -2     2229           2225         4      WN    530  N443WN    LGA    MDW      117
# 8827:    10     2104           2110        -6     2337           2355       -18      B6    529  N507JB    EWR    MCO      127
# 8828:    10     2129           2130        -1      148            218       -30      B6    701  N193JB    JFK    SJU      186
# 8829:    10     2159           2159         0     2247           2300       -13      EV   4519  N13124    EWR    BWI       33
# 8830:    10     2320           2250        30       16           2354        22      B6   1018  N612JB    JFK    BOS       35
# 8831:    10       NA            635        NA       NA            940        NA      AA    711  N3CDAA    LGA    DFW       NA
# 8832:    10       NA            700        NA       NA           1007        NA      UA    719            EWR    DFW       NA
# 6 variables not shown: [distance <int>, hour <int>, minute <int>, time_hour <POSc>, year <int>, month <int>]
```

Notes:

- If your system can afford to do so, it might be worth your effort to then iterate over each `year=?/month=?` subdirectory and combine all of the data into one file. Remember my mention of "many files, slow `open_dataset`"? Combining sibling `.parquet` files might help solve this. Again, this is only possible if you can read all of one subdir set into memory at a time. It might not be necessary, over to you.
- I used a "hive" partitioning/subdirectory scheme, where the `year=` implicitly creates the indexable column. (If you read one of the `1.parquet` *directory*, you'll note that it does not have `year` or `month` in them.) If this is not desired, you can create plainer path names (e.g., `2013/12/1.parquet`) and use `open_dataset("datamart2", partitions=c("year","month"))`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what the issue is.  You mention that opening each of 40 files is 14 seconds but that's not so long, under 10 minutes even if you open them one at a time.

You could open them in parallel if this is something happening frequently with a fresh 40 files and that 10 minutes is really important.

```
library(future)
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession) 
DT <- rbindlist(future_lapply(files, yourfunc))
```

It's likely you're going to be I/O constrained so who knows if that will help.

Can you change the upstream process that is generating these csv files?  If so, then I'd echo @r2evans recommendation of using `arrow` and the parquet file format instead of csv or even just to save the output.  It's much smaller and the data is typed so you don't need to worry about dates losing their dateness later.